# java XML parsing, the markup must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

My XML file is in the following format:

```
<top>
  <name></name>
  <title></title>
  <time></time>
</top>
<top>
  ...
</top>
<top>
  ...
</top>
```

I write the following code to read the xml file:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File(QUERY_FILE));  //LINE (*)
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("top");
```

But the problem is I get error as at line (*):

> The markup in the document following the root element must be
>   well-formed.

It seems that error is because I have multiple root elements in the xml file. One solution could be I add maybe `<doc></doc>` outside all `<top>` elements. But is there any other way that I can directly read in such XML file as element arrays?

Comment: your XML document has to have a root element.

Comment: @PTBG So there is no way that I do not have a root element and still can use the default parser?

Comment: @YitongZhou PTBG is right, you need a root element. All XML must have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to isolate each`<top>` element and trying to parse them separately, but that's a more troublesome solution than just wrapping `<doc></doc>` around the xml content..

One thing I've done in the past is instead of putting the root tags in the file itself, I just read the text into a string, and wrap the `<doc></doc>` tags around the string before  I load the XML.

Comment: Well, I guess I finally better wrap the text with a header, even it is quite lousy, maybe it is the simpliest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are add this line for well-formed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- this line-->
<top>
  <name></name>
  <title></title>
  <time></time>
</top>
```

Use this page to see if your document is correct, since it is the one that sets the standard for this metalanguage.
http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Validate xml dtd, etc ..

The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) is the main international standards organization for the World Wide Web (abbreviated WWW or W3).| Font Wikipedia